# [Mysql]: Inserting values into an intermediate table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have recently added an intermediary table to link two tables.

Tables:

```
Purchase:
Transaction_Id  Purchase_Id

Schedule:
Show_Id     Price

Purchase_Schedule:
PurchaseId(fk)   Show_Id(fk)
```

My problem is that purhcase_id is on auto_increment.  So i'm not sure where to pull that ID from.

I was going to do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO
    Purchase_Schedule
        (Purchase_ID, Show_ID)
    VALUES
        ((SELECT Purchase_ID FROM Purchase WHERE Transaction_ID=$transactionID),$purchaseID)";
```

The issue is that a Transaction_ID can have more than one purchase_ID tied to it... so this method is out.

So I believe the best way to approach this situation would be to use some sort of stored procedure to automatically update Purchase_Schedule.

**Should I go with a stored procedure?**
**Is there a way to insert into Purchase_Schedule @ the current insert's Purchase_ID?**
**or a way to return the auto_incremented Purchase_ID?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP to insert the data, you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to retrieve the value of the auto-incremented id for the last row inserted.

You can also get it via SQL:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

See [the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) for more information.